# Android Studio: Error: Qaulifier must be an expression

Tags: android, android-studio, syntax-error

I was creating run() and typed
`android.os.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);`

`android.os` red-lined and Android Studio said "Qualifier must be an expression" The problem of course was that it should have read `android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(android.os.Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_BACKGROUND);` but I overlooked the typo and spent about ten minutes googling for the error message. Does anyone want to explain what it means?